How to find the Inverse Laplace Transform of \$\frac{1}{(s^2+1)^2}\$ or \$\frac{s^2}{(s^2+1)^2}\$ by PFE?
From the Laplace transform table formula 11 and 12, we have \$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\frac{s^2}{(s^2+1)^2}\} =\frac{1}{2}(sin t + tcos t)\$ and \$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\frac{1}{(s^2+1)^2}\} =\frac{1}{2}(sin t - tcos t)\$. They can be derived from the convolution integral of \$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{F(s)G(s)\} =f(t)*g(t)\$.
$$
\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\frac{s^2}{(s^2+1)^2}\}=\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\frac{s}{s^2+1}\}* \mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\frac{s}{s^2+1}\}=cos \space t * cos\space t=\int_0^t cos(t-\tau)cos(\tau)\space d\tau\\\\=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t cos(t-2\tau)+cos(t)\space d\tau=\frac{1}{2}(sin\space t + t\space cos\space t)
$$
This is a convolution method, but can you show me how to solve it by Partial Fraction Expansion?

Use an online solver: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inverse-laplace-calculator/inverse%20laplace%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cleft(s%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B1%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%7D?or=input

A part of this question is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518777/inverse-laplace-transform-of-frac-1-s212

Note that \$ (s^2+1)^2 = (s+i)^2*(s-i)^2 \$.
Made with Maple.

You can then continue developing.

Good note and combined with the PFE with repeated poles give the same answer as the convolution method.

This is a note about the efficiency of using PFE(a.k.a. PFD) versus convolution integral in solving power of n type of Laplace transform. As an example, if we were to solve \$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\frac{1}{(s^2+1)^3}\}\$ with n=3 by convolution, we would successively apply the previous result of power n-1 (2 in this case):
$$
\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\frac{1}{(s^2+1)^3}\}=\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\frac{1}{(s^2+1)^2}\} * \mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\frac{1}{(s^2+1)}\}
=\frac{1}{2}(sin\ t - t\ cos\ t)*sin\ t=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t(sin\ \tau-\ \tau\ cos\ \tau)\ sin(t-\tau)\ d\tau=\frac{1}{4}\{sin\ t-t\ cos\ t - \int_0^t\tau\ [sin\ t + sin(t - 2\tau)]\ d\tau\}\\=\frac{1}{8}\{3\ sin\ t - 3\ t\ cos\ t - t^2\ sin\ t\} \tag{1}
$$
On the other hand, the PFE requires a whole new set of equations.
$$
\frac{1}{(s^2+1)^3}=\frac{A}{(s+j)^3}+\frac{B}{(s+j)^2}+\frac{C}{(s+j)}+\frac{D}{(s-j)^3}+\frac{E}{(s-j)^2}+\frac{F}{(s-j)} \tag{2}\\\\
$$
$$
(s-j)^3\{A+B(s+j)+C(s+j)^2\}+(s+j)^3\{D+E(s-j)+F(s-j)^2\}=1 \tag{3} 
$$
Setting \$s=\pm j\$ in Eq.3 yield \$A=-\frac{j}{8}\$ and \$D=\frac{j}{8}\$. 
Setting \$s=0\$, \$s=\pm 2j\$ and \$s=\pm 3j\$  in Eq.3 yield \$B = -\frac{3}{16}\$, \$C=\frac{3}{16}j\$, \$E=-\frac{3}{16}\$ and \$F=-\frac{3}{16}j\$.
Substituting constants A through F back to Eq.2 results in Eq.1.
This takes 8 simultaneous equations to tediously arrive at the answer.
